# Why does corepack try to install yarn v1.22 by default when v4.11 is the latest?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, nvm, corepack

I can see corepack about to download yarn v1.22 when I run the `yarn` command:

```
user@laptop:~/empty-directory$ yarn
Corepack is about to download https://registry.yarnpkg.com/yarn/-/yarn-1.22.22.tgz.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I'm using corepack v0.25.2.

The latest release of yarn is v4.11 at the time of writing: https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/releases

Why is this version being downloaded, and how can I make yarn 4.1.1 the default version that Corepack uses?

Comment: Please can someone with 1500+ reputation create the `yarnpkg-v4` tag. The preceeding versions all have their own (1 through 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the packageManger field in package.json is not specified, Corepack will download the **global** version of the package manager that Corepack is configured with (Corepack also calls these 'Known Good Releases'). To use a different version of yarn, you can either:

- Set the packageManger field in your project's package.json to your preferred version (e.g. `"packageManger": "yarn@4.1.1"`), then run `yarn` to install the dependencies using that package manager version.
- Update Corepack's Known Good Release for yarn with `corepack up -g yarn@4.1.1`.

---

### Links

- Useful issue on the Corepack Github discussing upgrading globally installed package managers: https://github.com/nodejs/corepack/issues/395
- Known Good Releases Corepack documentation: https://github.com/nodejs/corepack?tab=readme-ov-file#known-good-releases